# Webシステムの動きについて

Tags: django

Webシステム自体が初心者です。

Djangoを使用した、webシステムを勉強しています。

デスクトップシステムでは、ある入力項目にユニークなコードを入力すると、カーソルがその項目から離れた際に、自動でそのコードに紐付く名称を表示させる流れが基本ですが、webシステムでも同じなのでしょうか？

例）商品コード項目を入力すると、その項目の横に商品名が表示されるなど

同じであれば、それをDjango で実現するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

また、違うのであれば、webシステムでの基本的な流れを教えてもらえないでしょうか？

色々調べたのですが、これといった解決策を探すことができませんでした。

以上、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

> webシステムでも同じなのでしょうか？

同じですね。

> 同じであれば、それをDjango で実現するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

- Ajaxを使う
- 画面を表示する際に、予めコードとそれに紐付く名称を取得しておいて、JavaScriptで表示させる

とかですかね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Ajaxについて調べてみます！